# Show that n is a power of 2!

Tags: number-theory

Prove that,if $2^n+1$ is a prime,$n$ is a power of $2$.

That's what I thought:
Suppose that $n$ is not a power of $2$.So,it will be have the form: $n=2k+q, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.Now we have,$2^n+1=2^{2k+q}+1=2^{2k}2^q+1>1$,so it has a prime divisor $p$.$$p|2^{2k}2^q+1$$

Is it right so far..and how can I continue?

Comment: You dodged a bullet there, evinda! An exclamation mark after a number means 'factorial' around these parts. But that's OK, because $2!$ is equal to $2$.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, to show that something is not a prime, you need to find a non-trivial factor. You need to tackle $2^n+1$ as a whole and not just the $2^n$ bit - the $+1$ makes a big difference.

Observe that if $n$ is not a power of $2$ it has an odd prime factor $p$ so that $n=pq$.

What can you do with $2^{pq}+1$ to show that it has a non-trivial factor (doesn't matter whether the factor is prime or not). If you have your wits about you, there is essentially only one thing you can do.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that if $p$ is an odd prime that divides $n$, then

$$ 2 ^ \frac{n}{p} + 1 \mid 2^n + 1 .$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** We know that $a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}$ is always divisible through $a+b$. Remember, for instance, the famous formula for the sum of two cubes, $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$. In our case, $b=1$, and $a=2^x$ where $n=x(2k+1)$, since *n* is not a power of $2$, and therefore has at least one odd factor.